# guake autostart file disappears after reboot

Tags: 22.04, autostart

I am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I installed Guake, and created a file called guake.desktop in ~/.config/autostart with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Guake Terminal
Comment=Use the command line in a Quake-like terminal
TryExec=guake
Exec=/usr/bin/guake
Icon=guake
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;System;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
```

Guake starts automatically when I logout and log back in, the problem is that the file is gone after a restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add your Guake program to the autostart by using the special GNOME program to achieve this instead of doing it by hand. You can start this program as follows:

```
$> gnome-session-properties
```

Comment: hi, it worked after the first restart, but not after the second restart. This is weird.

Comment: ohh the Guake preferences has a setting for auto start at login, perhaps the file was conflicting with Guake's own internals. thanks.